# Sum of digits of number from 1 to n

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, decimal-expansion

> Is there any general formula for calculating the sum of **digits** of number from $1$ to $n$?
>
> $n < 10^9$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I just want to know if there is any general formula for the above problem if it exists?

Comment: I could think of some things, they don't look pretty though. Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: there are some questions that are present on different coding websites which asks for this type of question..please explain if u have something

Comment: There's a difference between producing a formula and programming a program that calculates this. The latter is much easier.

Comment: So for $n=10$, we have $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+1$?

Comment: @JackM yeah..like that only

Comment: https://oeis.org/A037123

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make the counting easier I will consider the sum of the digits of all integers from $0$ to $n$ - clearly this does not change the answer.  Denote this sum by $D(n)$.

**Edit**.  Here is an improved answer.  As a couple of people thought my previous answer was worth upvoting I have not deleted it, see below.

Write $n=10q+r$ where $q\ge0$ and $0\le r\le 9$.  The digits of all numbers from $0$ to $n$ can be split into the following four sets:

- the units digits of numbers from $0$ to $10q-1$;
- the other digits of numbers from $0$ to $10q-1$;
- the units digits of numbers from $10q$ to $10q+r$;
- the other digits of numbers from $10q$ to $10q+r$.

The first group consists of the digits from $0$ to $9$ repeated $q$ times each.  The second consists of the digits of the numbers $0,1,\ldots,q-1$ repeated $10$ times each.  The third consists of the digits $0,1,\ldots,r$.  The fourth consists of the digits of $q$ repeated $r+1$ times.  So if we write $d(q)$ for the sum of the digits of $q$, we obtain the **recursive formula**
$$D(10q+r)=45q+10D(q-1)+\frac{r(r+1)}{2}+(r+1)d(q)\ .$$

---

Here is my **previous answer**.  First consider all numbers from $0$ to $10^k-1$.  There are $10^k$ such numbers, each having $k$ digits if we allow leading zeros.  This gives $k10^k$ digits altogether, and they are equally distributed among the $10$ possibilities, $k10^{k-1}$ of each digit.  So
$$D(10^k-1)=k10^{k-1}(0+1+\cdots+9)=(45k)10^{k-1}\ .$$

Next consider $n=a10^k-1$, where $1\le a\le9$.  All of the above occur $a$ times over; there are also the initial digits $0,1,\ldots,a-1$ occurring $10^k$ times each.  So
$$D(a10^k-1)=(45ak)10^{k-1}+(1+\cdots+(a-1))10^k=(45ak)10^{k-1}+\frac{a(a-1)}{2}10^k\ .$$

Finally consider $n=a10^k+b$ with $1\le a\le 9$ and $0\le b<10^k$.  The sum of the digits includes all the above; and all the numbers from $0$ to $b$, with an initial digit $a$ prepended.  Thus we obtain a **recursive formula** which may perhaps in practice be the easiest way to calculate $D(n)$: if $1\le a\le 9$ and $0\le b<10^k$, then
$$D(a10^k+b)=(45ak)10^{k-1}+\frac{a(a-1)}{2}10^k+a(b+1)+D(b)\ .$$

Comment: great explanation sir..thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

There is no rational function (formula involving only $+$, $-$, $\cdot$ and $/$) that does this. Indeed, for $n = 100...00$, we have $f(n+1)=f(n)+2$. Therefore the function $f(x+1)-f(x)$, which is also rational, takes on the value $2$ an infinite number of times, but a rational function cannot take on the same value an infinite number of times unless it's constant, and $f(x+1)-f(x)$ is clearly not constant.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=\sum_{i=0}^k10^i\cdot n_i$, so the $n_i$ are the decimal digits of $n$. Let $[x]$ denote the integer part of $x$. Then the sum $S$ of all digits of all integers up to $n$ is

$$S=\sum_{i=0}^kn_i\cdot\left(n+1-10^i\cdot\left[\frac{n}{10^i}\right]\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^k10^in_i(n_i-1)+45\cdot\sum_{i=0}^k\left[\frac{n}{10^{i+1}}\right].$$

As I feared, it's very ugly. From the edit in your question (stating $n<10^9$) I would guess it's a programming question. Programming a loop is much nicer for such small numbers.

Comment: ok..let me check whether it is correct or not

Comment: should n = sum(10 ^ k * n (i)) or n = sum(10 ^ i * n (i))

Comment: it will be helpful if you will explain this with an example..i am not getting it correctly

Comment: Fixed the index in the first sum, thank you for noticing. I haven't tried plugging numbers into the formula. Does it not give the correct values?

Comment: i am not getting correct value..maybe my approach is wrong..i was trying for n = 45

Comment: Then $k=1$, $n_0=5$ and $n_1=4$ yielding
$$S=\tfrac{1}{2}(20+30)+45(4+0)=205,$$
which seems right to me, unless I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: i think the answer should be 279

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to find, through several calculations, a general recursive formula for the sum of the digits fom $0$ to $n$, which I denoted by $Dg(n)$.
However, $n$ has to be written using the positional notation, namely $10^z\alpha+10^{z-1}\beta+10^{z-2}\gamma+...+\omega$, where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,...,\omega$ are the digits of $n$ in order from left to right, and $z+1$ corresponds to the number of digits of n.
That being said, the formula is
$$
Dg(10^z\alpha+10^{z-1}\beta+10^{z-2}\gamma+\cdots+\omega)=
$$
$$
=\alpha(45\times z\times 10^{z-1}+1+10^{z-1}\beta+10^{z-2}\gamma+\cdots+\omega)++Dg(10^{z-1}\beta+10^{z-2}\gamma+\cdots+\omega)+10^z\times T_{\alpha-1}
$$
where $T_n$ is the nth triangular number.

The calculation ends when the recursion reaches $Dg(\omega)$, which is equal to $\frac{\omega(\omega+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of consecutive natural numbers can be calculated with this formula:

n/2[2a + (n-1) x d] where:

n = total number of consecutive natural numbers to be summed
d = difference between two consecutive natural numbers (generally 1)
a = first natural number

Thus, sum of digits 1 to 100 is:

100/2(2+99x1) = 50 x 101 = 5050

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).